# What is the remainder of $|e-\sum_{j=0}^n{1\over j!}|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I have to find the smallest $n$ such that $|e-\sum_{j=0}^n{1\over j!}|<0.001$, but I want to do it with the remainder. I know that it is ${e^c\over (n+1)!}$ where $0<c<1$, but how do you get that? Furthermore, how, with this $e^c$ standing in the middle, can you find this $n$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder term is obtained by expanding the Taylor's polynomial of $\exp$ about $x_0 = 0$ and applying Taylor's Theorem at $x = 1$. If you desire $|\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}| < 0.001$, you may ask for the sufficient condition $\frac{e}{(n+1)!} < 0.001$, since $c < 1$ and $\exp$ is increasing. By trial and error,
$$6! = 720 < \frac{e}{0.001} < 5040 = 7!$$
Therefore, taking $n = 6$ you can make sure the remainder term is small enough.

Comment: Why did you then treat is as $e$ only?

Comment: That is really important for me to know. This is the second time I am posting this question, asking about another about which aspect no referring was given in the first time, even though I asked... I don't want to post another one asking for another specified thing...

Comment: Because it is a necessary condition. For $c \in (0,1)$, we have $e^c < e$. By necessary condition, I mean if $\frac{e}{(n+1)!} < 0.001$ for a certain $n$, then it can be made sure that $|\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}| < \frac{e}{(n+1)!} < 0.001$, which is desired. You can replace $e^c$ by a larger upper bound for $e^c$, say 10, instead of $e$ too. But then the $n$ we solve for would be larger. So I used the least upper bound $e$.